# Barry Simon quote

Tags: soft-question, math-history

In the back of my mind, I have the strong recollection (though perhaps I am confabulating) that Barry Simon once jokingly wrote something akin to

"Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, taken to be separable (are there any other sort?)..."

Can anybody please confirm this, and offer a reference to where the real quote was written?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's how section 1.1 of "Trace Ideals and Their Applications" begins:

> Throughout, all our Hilbert spaces will be *complex and separable* (are there any
>   others?)...

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. :)